# Codeigniter error while saving sessions: please try again later

Tags: php

I am using a login script via ajax in Codeigniter and an error:

> An error occured please try again later

pops up. These are the two lines removal of any of these removes the error but I need both of these to execute:

```
$this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
$this->session->set_userdata('permissions', $permissions_from_db);
```

Here `$userdata` is an array having users info retrieved from db and `$permissions_from_db` is another array which also have data retrieved from db.
does setting sessions one after another causing problem? or does there is an upper limit on number of items I can store as session?

Comment: Unfortunately that error message doesn't say much. If you can turn on more error reporting that would help. Are you writing session data anywhere else? does that work?

Comment: My CodeIgniter installation doesn't appear to contain the error string you specified. Is this your error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just need to change this line

```
$this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
```

to

```
$this->session->set_userdata('user_data', $user_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Load a library file of session into a constructor.

   ```
   function __constructor() {
       $this->load->library('session');    
   }
   ```
2. Set the session variable into your method or function like this way:

   ```
   $this->session->set_userdata($data);   
   $this->session->set_userdata('users_data', $data);
   ```